# Scala - method variables not immutable

Tags: scala, jvm

Seems like a bug in Scala, it lets you mutate a method variable names.

In this example, the compiler should never have allowed the parameter `name` to be declared again in the same method block.

```
object App {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    testMethod()
  }

  def testMethod(name: String = "John Smith"): Unit = {
    val name = "John Doe"
    println(name)
  }

}
```

Is there any explanation for mutating a method variable names ?

**Output**

```
John Doe
```

Comment: Local variable and method parameter are different.

Comment: The `name` argument is being shadowed, not mutated. To demonstrate, make the new `name` a different type: `val name = 77`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not bug, but a feature. This is called [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

What really could have been a bug, if you could do this:

```scala
def testMethod(name: String = "John Smith"): Unit = {
  name = "John Doe" // does not compile
  println(name)
}
```

Note `name` is not val and trying to re-assign new value to incoming argument